# calling methods in each other in Rational class

Tags: java, math, methods, data-structures

this is a sample of my class Rational which i build it and make the math and the algorithms in every method

```
public class Rational {

private int Numerator;
private int Denominator;

public Rational() {
    Numerator = 1;
    Denominator = 1;
}

public Rational(int a, int b) {
    if (b == 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(" Cannot divide by zero ");
    }
    this.Numerator = a;
    this.Denominator = b;
}
```

my problem is that i do not want to repeat the methods every time like you know that divide operation is multiply operation with inverting the other rational number but the problem here that i dont know **how to call the method multiply in divide** in this case :

```
public Rational multiply(Rational other) {
    int numerator = this.Numerator * other.Numerator;
    int denominator = this.Denominator * other.Denominator;
    return new Rational(numerator, denominator);
}

public Rational divide(Rational other) {
    other.invert();
    return null;// where to call the multiply method ?
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Rational` should almost certainly be immutable: the two fields should be final.

The reason is that mutable `Rational` makes it near-impossible to reason about: you simply can't rely on the value not being changed somewhere else in your program, so you can't know what the result of a calculation will be.

The invert method should return a new instance of rational, that you can then pass to `multiply`:

```
return multiply(other.invert());
```